# Finding prime numbers in python : why the output starts with 2

Tags: python

```
for num in range(2,101):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break  
    else :
        print(num, end = ' ')
```

I don't understand why the output starts from 2

I thought `num` starts with 2, and the `i` also starts with 2

so, `(num % i) == 0` is right

What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `num == 2`, `range(2, num)` is empty, because ranges stop *before* the end number.

So `for i in range(2, num):` never executes the body in that case, and therefore it never tests `num % i == 0`. The loop ends immediately, without executing `break`, so it goes into the `else:` block.